# What does the #*$ in a shell script's string interpolation do?

Tags: bash, sh

I found the following code in a shell script, but I am unsure of what the `test` condition is evaluating for

```sh
if test "${SOME_VAR#*$from asdf/qwer}" != "$SOME_VAR"; then
  echo "##zxcv[message text='some text.' status='NORMAL']";
fi
```

Comment: `#*$` does not mean anything special but `${SOME_VAR#abc}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) that means `$SOME_VAR` with the shortest prefix that match `abc` removed. Type `man bash` in your terminal to read the documentation of `bash` or [read it online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination `#*$` does not mean anything special. There are three special symbols and each of them has its own meaning in this context.

`${SOME_VAR#abc}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Its value is the value of `$SOME_VAR` with the shortest prefix that matches `abc` removed.

In your example, `abc` is `*${from} asdf/qwer`. That means anything `*` followed by the value of variable `$from` (which is dynamic and replaced when the expression is evaluated), followed by a space and followed by `asdf/qwer`.

All in all, if the value of `$SOME_VAR` starts with a string that ends in `${from} asdf/qwer` then everything before and including `asdf/qwer` is removed and the resulting value is passed as the first argument to `test`.

Type `man bash` in your terminal to read the documentation of `bash` or [read it online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).